# Dual citizen (UK Passport & Aus Citizenship) travelling to Australia on holiday

Tags: visas, uk, passports, australia, dual-nationality

What are the Australian entry requirements for a child travelling to Australia on a UK passport and Australian Citizenship (by Descent)?

Will child be refused entry without an Australian passport?

Will child be refused entry with a valid tourist visa (651) on their UK passport?

Edit: Australian Government website seems to suggest a visa is not available for dual nationals (however we have one); and an Australian passport **should** be used to avoid delays (we don't have one).
Edit: Child is travelling with parents whom both hold applicable documentation.

Comment: I can't say what will happen if you travel, but it seems the easiest way to avoid problems is to [go get your child's Australian passport](http://uk.embassy.gov.au/lhlh/PptsApply.html).

Comment: If you already have the visa, just use it.  They cannot deny entry to an Australian citizen, so you could pull that out of the hat if they try to deny entry under the visa.  That's extremely unlikely, of course.  If the child shows up with the British passport and visa, what would make them suspect that the child is Australian?

Comment: @phoog The fact that the parents are Australian?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that does seem like the most likely reason.  The question, however, does not indicate whether the child is traveling with his or her parents.

Answer (score 4):

An Australian citizen cannot be refused entry into Australia, so no, the child is not going to be turned back. It may take some time to cross-check though, and if flagged as an Australian, departing the country without an Australian passport will be more complicated.

I would have expected some trouble when applying for the visa, which as you correctly state should not have been granted to an Australian citizen, but since it was granted anyway, you should be fine in practice.

Comment: No where on the guidance or application is a query on Australian citizenship. So either this is deliberate or a flaw in their application process.